# Assigning signal to itself fails

Tags: vhdl

This code is not mapping `8` to `paddle_out` as expected:

```
 entity GAME is
  port(
      --L : in std_logic;
      --R : in std_logic;
      clk    : in std_logic;
      paddle_out : out unsigned (9 downto 0)
  );    
end;

architecture GAME_ARCH of GAME is
    signal paddle : unsigned (9 downto 0) := 10d"8";
begin

  process (clk) is
  begin
    if rising_edge(clk) then

      -- PADDLE (changes 'paddle')
      --if L = '1' and R = '0' then
        --paddle <= paddle - 1 when paddle >= 63;
      --elsif L = '0' and R = '1' then
        --paddle <= paddle + 1 when paddle <= 495; -- 575-80 (rightmost edge of screen minus width of paddle)
      --end if;

    paddle_out <= paddle;
    paddle <= paddle + 0;

    end if;
  end process;
end;
```

If I remove `paddle <= paddle` this seems to work.

**What is happening here?**

Testing module:

```
entity TEST is
   port(test : out unsigned(9 downto 0));
end;

architecture test_arch of TEST is

component HSOSC is
    generic (CLKHF_DIV : String := "0b00");
    port (
        CLKHFPU : in  std_logic := '1';
        CLKHFEN : in  std_logic := '1';
        CLKHF   : out std_logic := 'X'
    );
end component;

component GAME is
   port(
      clk : in std_logic;
      paddle_out : out unsigned (9 downto 0)
  );
end component;

    signal clock : std_logic;
begin
    my_clock : HSOSC port map('1', '1', clock);
    my_game  : GAME  port map(clock, test);
end;
```

Comment: Show us all relevant code. Are there other processes assigning values to `paddle`? Assigning `paddle` to itself does not make sense, because it is a register which holds its value. `out` is a reserved word in VHDL, choose another name for your entity port.

Comment: There are another 2 processes running, but none of them modifies paddle. paddle is assigning to itself is because of a minimization of my bug. Original code was conditionally assigning values dependent on paddle. I think I might give up and go to sleep. And never touch hardware in my life again.

Comment: We need an [MCVE].

Comment: @MatthewTaylor. Does this mean that this should be working as is? Because if so, I'll just replace my fpga.

Comment: What are the printed error logs ?

Comment: I do not know what is inside your HSOSC component, but maybe you have to give a value to CLKHF_DIV (that is set by default to 0)

Comment: Also, is it the complete file ? I do not see the headers 
LIBRARY IEEE;
USE IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
USE IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

Comment: HSOSC is fine. Apparently according to our prof it is UB to now assign something to a signal every cycle. Our project didn’t quite work sadly, but then again it gave me good motivation to never use VHDL again